# Convert Active Directory user to local machine user

Tags: active-directory, authentication, windows-server-2000

I am trying to convert user profiles in Windows Server 2000 from using an Active Directory authentication to using local machine authentication (it's currently on an AD network that is deprecated and being removed).  The thing being that I need to maintain all of the user Documents and Settings information (including username and password to login), just change it to never use the AD login and just authenticate locally.  I am not extremely proficient at Windows Server (more of a linux guy) and didn't see any relevant options in the "Users and Passwords" panel.  Thanks for any help.

PS: I wasn't sure if this should be in SF or SU, but figured since it was dealing with AD it would be a better fit here, let me know if you think I should move it there instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't too fun as its a pretty manual process in my experience. I'm not sure why the need to do this but here you go.

All these steps are on the PC Create a local user account. 
Log in as newly created user. 
Log in as another user ie local admin.
Right click my computer, properties, advanced, user profiles and use the tool to copy the domain profile to the newly created local user.
Sometimes the ntuser.dat file stays in use so you may need to reboot after some of the steps.

Saved passwords may or may not copy over so make sure that the user knows them.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at user profile wizard.  It's free for small shops, you can migrate a local profile to a domain, and I'm pretty sure you can go the other direction like you are trying.

It takes care of changing all of the permissions and making sure your "new" account can access an existing profile on the machine.

It was originally developed to help multiple users share an a single local profile on a windows box, so I'm pretty sure they've still left that functionality in there.

http://www.forensit.com/domain-migration.html

Comment: I confirm it is possible to convert an AD user to a local one with this tool (it worked perfectly for me). To be noted: this tool does not make a copy of the AD profile, but instead redirects the local profile to the old one (the C:\Users\ folder will be left unchanged).